# Is possible to increase timeout for automation studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, timeout

I have several SQL activities that are facing timeouts and I would like to know if it is possible to increase the time to get timeouts and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to extend the timeout beyond the standard 30 minutes. If your queries take more than that, they are most likely in need of optimisation. One method could be splitting them in multiple queries, and utilising staging data extension.

You should focus on how your data is indexed. Primary keys in a data extension are always automatically indexed. Hence it would be beneficial to ensure you are joining data extensions on their primary keys. Also, keep the width of a data extension within 4000 characters, and avoid using too large fields for text. Doing so reduces the amount of work necessary to store and retrieve data from your data extensions. Precisely constructed data extensions help to avoid inefficient data storage which can degrade overall performance. Only use unbounded columns, those fields whose length is not set, when no other option is available.

Do check your quesries, and avoid using non searchable operators, such as:

- OR operators
- NOT
- `>`
- `<`
- NOT EXISTS
- NOT IN
- NOT LIKE

More advice on optimizing queries and data extensions can be found:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_best_practices_data_extensions_query_activities.htm&type=5